# MergEx MergeDataGrid Scroller

Tags: datagrid, livecode

I've got you MergeDataGrid Scroller for a stack that should work on OS X,Win and mobile.
I have 2 problems:
1st problem:
since I decided to put 2 different option buttons on the data grid (hiding one or the other according to mobile or OS X/Win), when I refresh the data grid I get this error:

> 573,3,1,resetList 241,3,1,mouseup 353,0,0,button id 46466 of card id
>   46375 of stack "revPropertyPalette 1"

Trying to open the script return "no such card".
Of course the data grid does not draw correctly.
This is the row behavior:

```
on FillInData pDataArray
     set the text of field "DossierName" of me to pDataArray["DossierName"]
     set the text of field "DossierDetails" of me to pDataArray["DossierDetails"]
     set the text of field "DossierTemplate" of me to pDataArray["TemplateName"]
     if the environment = "Mobile" then
          show group "Dossier_Status" of me
          hide button "Dossier_StatusDesktop" of me
          put line pDataArray["DossierStatus"] of gDialogs[34] into gCurrentSelectedValue
          set the label of button "Dossier_Status" of me to gCurrentSelectedValue
     else --desktop
           hide group "Dossier_Status" of me
           show button "Dossier_StatusDesktop" of me
           set the content of btn "Dossier_StatusDesktop" of me to gDialogs[34]
           set the label of button "Dossier_StatusDesktop" of me to line pDataArray["DossierStatus"] of gDialogs[34]
          end if
end FillInData
```

2nd problem:
Before the above change (the two buttons) the stack was working fine on OS X. But on iOS simulator or iPad2 fisical, if there was data on the data grid, the App would crash without messages (after OpenCard). How can I find out the problem from the apple crash report ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think either of these issues are related to mergDataGridScroller.

The error is being thrown by the property palette in the LiveCode IDE. I would need to have a copy of your stack to debug the cause of the error but one thing stands out in your script: Is "Dossier_Status" a group or a button or do you have both a group and a button named "Dossier_Status"?

```
show group "Dossier_Status" of me
...
set the label of button "Dossier_Status" of me to gCurrentSelectedValue
```

Regarding the crash as mergDataGridScroller is just a script then if the script is causing a crash then that is an engine bug. Scripts should not cause an app to crash.

Comment: Correct: there is a group and there is a button.

Comment: Regarding the second point, the reason for my writing is that if the data grid is empty there is no crash. Being the crash so late on stack loading (after the open card) I tough it could be a problem of timing in loading the data grid data. Is this a possibility? should I put a few "send" in the ordering and filling of the data grid?

Comment: If you are getting a reliable crash then you should report it the LiveCode bug database http://quality.livecode.com